# vb6 error - expected procedure not variable

Tags: vb6

hey i get the above error mentioned in the title when i press my search button

here is the code

i tried setting a break point and running the code but as soon as i press my search button an error message "EXPECTED PROCEDURE NOT VARIABLE" pops up

im quite new to vb6 programming .. can anyone help ?

```
   Private Sub cmdsearch_Click()

    If txtvehiclenumber = "" Then
       MsgBox " Please enter a vehicle number"
    Else

rsFiveGallonDelivery " select * from FiveGallonDelivery where Cstr(VehicleNumber) =  '" & txtvehiclenumber & "'", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

If Not rsFiveGallonDelivery.BOF And Not rsFiveGallonDelivery.EOF Then
rsFiveGallonDelivery.MoveFirst
     txtdate = rsFiveGallonDelivery.Fields("Date")
     txtdeliverytimeoutrs = FiveGallonDelivery("DeliveryTimeOut")
     txtdeliverytimeinrs = FiveGallonDelivery("DeliveryTimeIn")
     txtfromfactory = rsFiveGallonDelivery.Fields("FromFactory")
     txtdeliverynotecount = rsFiveGallonDelivery.Fields("DeliveryNoteCount")
     txtfromoperations = rsFiveGallonDelivery.Fields("FromOperations")
     txtnormaldeliveries = rsFiveGallonDelivery.Fields("NormalDeliveries")
     txtnewdeliveries = rsFiveGallonDelivery.Fields("NewDeliveries")
     txtbottleincreases = rsFiveGallonDelivery.Fields("BottleIncreases")
     txtpromotions = rsFiveGallonDelivery.Fields("Promotions")
     txtreturnstooperations = rsFiveGallonDelivery.Fields("ReturnsToOperations")
     txtreturnstofactory = rsFiveGallonDelivery.Fields("ReturnsToFactory")
     txtfactorycount = rsFiveGallonDelivery.Fields("FactoryCount")

   Else
     MsgBox " No Such record "
  End If
  rsFiveGallonDelivery.Close

  End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds like a compiler error and not a run-time error. If you want to find all the problems like this before running your app, then use the "Run with full compile" option (`Ctrl+F5`). Otherwise, VB6 compiles each method as you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is rsFiveGallonDelivery ?

your code now treats it as a procedure (that is what the error message is) ..

if it is a string then place a "=" between the variable and the data

if it is a recordset (which i guess it is) then call the correct function to run the sql query after it

Comment: yes it is a recordset .. could you please explain what "call the correct function to run the sql query after it" means 
thank you :)

Comment: adding .open fixed that problem nut now it highlights line 5 with the error "object variable or with block variable not set"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to open a recordset?

```
rsFiveGallonDelivery.Open " select *...
```